# How to show $e^{2 \pi i \theta}$ is not algebraic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

I was wondering if someone could possibly help
me figure out how to show $e^{2 \pi i \theta}$
is not algebraic when $\theta$ is irrational.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that as stated the result is not correct. For example, there is a real number $t$ such that $\cos(2\pi t)$ is equal to $\dfrac{3}{5}$, and it can be shown that $t$ is not rational. But if $\theta$ is an irrational **algebraic** number, then indeed $e^{2\pi i\theta}$ is transcendental.

Comment: Oops. My apologies. Thank you!

Comment: How does this help one understand the assertion? Could you shed some more light upon the question? Thanks for the attention in any case.

Comment: @awllower: There are many irrationals $\theta$ such that $e^{2\pi i \theta}$ is rational, and in particular algebraic. The correct result is that if $\theta$ is an **algebraic** irrational then $e^{2\pi i \theta}$ is transcendental. That is straight Lindemann-Weierstrass.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem