# Multiplying by $2\pi i$ in the exponent in the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

The Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem tells us for which algebraic $\alpha$ the exponential $e^{\alpha}$ is also algebraic. I wonder what happens
when we replace $\alpha$ by $2\pi i \alpha$. In other words, for which algebraic $\alpha$ is $e^{2\pi i\alpha}$ also algebraic ?

My thoughts : obviously, if $\alpha$ is rational then $e^{2\pi i\alpha}$ is a root of unity and so is algebraic.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306309/how-to-show-e2-pi-i-theta-is-not-algebraic) is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the idea is discussed in the commented link. To finish this problem, assume on the contrary that $\beta=e^{2\pi i \alpha}$ is algebraic for an algebraic irrational $\alpha$.  Then 
$$
\frac{\log \beta}{\log(-1)} = \frac{2 \pi i\alpha}{\pi i} = 2\alpha.
$$

Now, this implies that $\beta = (-1)^{2\alpha}$ with algebraic irrational $\alpha$. This contradicts [Gelfond-Schneider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).